# REGEX удалить все теги внутри скобок

Tags: регулярные-выражения, теги

Имеется текст:

```
{<img>content</img><img src="some-pic-url">content</img>o}
<a> content </a> <a href="url">content</a>
<a href="url">content</img>
<img src="some-pic-url">content</a>
<a href="url">content
<img src="some-pic-url"/>content
```

Необходимо удалить все теги внутри фигурных скобок, чтобы получился такой результат:

```
{contentcontento}
<a> content </a> <a href="url">content</a>
<a href="url">content</img>
<img src="some-pic-url">content</a>
<a href="url">content
<img src="some-pic-url"/>content
```

Выражение `(?:<).*?(?:>)` может найти все теги во всем тексте.
Выражение `(?={).*(?<=})` может найти что нибудь внутри скобок.
Два этих выражения вместе, чтобы найти все теги внутри скобок, не работают `(?={)(?:<).*?(?:>)(?<=})`

Да, можно в коде циклом искать подстроки и работать с ними, но неужели нет возможности сделать все в одной регулярке?

Ссылка с примером где можно проверить https://regex101.com/r/EHXEXh/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|{)[^{}]*?\K<[^<>]*>(?=[^{}]*})
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ZSRRKS/1).

*Подробности*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|{)` - конец предыдущего совпадения или символ `{`
- `[^{}]*?` - ноль и более символов, отличных от `{` и `}`, но как можно меньше
- `\K`  - забыть всё, что было найдено до этого места
- `<[^<>]*>` - `<`, ноль и более символов, отличных от `<` и `>`, а потом `>`
- `(?=[^{}]*})` - сразу после должно быть ноль и более символов, отличных от `{` и `}`, а потом `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант, по которому я пока не готов предоставить расшифровку, так как пока не разобрался как работает, но он работает:

```
(?=[^{]*\})(?:<).*?(?:>)
```